# How to append an array in the second level in a document in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb-python

If I have a multiple level document:

```
{
    "id": "eb533cd0-fef1-48bf-9fb8-b66261c9171b" ,
    "task": {
        "errors": [
            "error1" ,
            "error2"
        ],
        "url":"localhost"
    }
}
```

How can I append a element to array "errors"?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with `merge`.

```
doc.merge({"task" : {"errors" : doc["task"]["errors"].append("value")}})
```

Comment: I ended up `get`ting the document from the database, manipulating it in python and then `replace`ing it back.  Thank you for the answer. Your answer is definitely more professional though.

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that your method of getting the document and manipulating it in python isn't atomic which means if it's being done concurrently you're running the risk of appends being lost.